# Rails Best_in_place ajax:success not being recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, best-in-place

My Rails app contains an Excel-like editable table, using best_in_place fields throughout. They work perfectly fine upon page load and I have no problem calling coffeescript functions on `ajax:success` after a user edits a best_in_place field.

Since this is an Excel-like table, users can click a link to add a new placeholder row to the table. My create.js.erb file adds the row without a page reload. The new row has several table cells with best_in_place functionality, and updating them updates the database, so far so good.

The problem is that when a user then edits a best_in_place fields in one of the **new** rows, `ajax:success` does not fire, therefore my coffeescript functions do not initiate.

I've confirmed the new table cells have the exact same class and data attributes as the existing table cells (`ajax:success` is read on the class name).

Question- in this scenario, how do I initiate my coffeescript function if `ajax:success` is not being recognized?

**Milestone controller, both create and update actions**

```
def create
@payment_schedule = PaymentSchedule.find(params[:id])
build_default_milestone # this builds a placeholder milestone
if @milestone.save
  increment_milestone_positions # this relates to a sortable table
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
  end
end
end

def update
@milestone = Milestone.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @milestone.update(milestone_params)
    update_milestone_amounts
    format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
    format.json { respond_with_bip(@milestone) }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
    format.json { respond_with_bip(:back) }
  end
end
end
```

**Create.js.erb**

```
$('#milestone-body').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'row_add', locals: { milestone: @milestone }) %>');
```

**Coffeescript function**

`update-percent` is the class name of the best_in_place field in question. This function fires perfectly for the existing rows, just not the new ones.

```
$('.update-percent').on 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
  ...
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: "An Excel-like editable table" = spreadsheet

Comment: You could check jQuerys `ajaxComplete()` fn and leter check for a success in it. [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The problem was not that ajax:success wasn't firing, it's that (for reasons still unknown) I had to read ajax:success at the table body level instead of the table cell in question. Apparently this is a somewhat common issue, where when adding new elements to the DOM after it's originally loaded, you need to read ajax:success higher up the DOM.

Thank you to those who provided input.

Answer (score 0):

are you using turbo links? I think best in place binds to document ready which acts funky if you are using turbo links. If so, remove it from your application.html.erb and application.js file and try again.

Comment: removed turbolinks from Gemfile, application.html.erb, and application.js...unfortunately still not recognizing `ajax:success`. You are right that it binds to document ready via `$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
})`, this is in my application.js file.